# Warum heißt „Fein Zucker“ nicht „Feiner Zucker“?

Tags: adjective, grammaticality

Weil es ein Adjektiv mit einem Substantiv ist, würde ich „Feiner Zucker“ sagen. Warum heißt das Produkt nicht so?

[image: Fein Zucker]

Comment: Fein Zucker. Lecker Bier. Hein Blöd.

Comment: Bei rein deskriptiver Analyse kann man für den Bestandteil „Produktbezeichnung“ der Textsorte „Verpackungsaufdruck“ die orthographische Besonderheit feststellen, dass ein Zeilenumbruch als alternatives Kopplungszeichen dient. Allgemein gehorchen solche Minimaltexte oft eigenen Regeln, nicht nur orthographischen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Es handelt sich hier um ein zusammengesetztes Nomen (Adjektiv + Nomen, sh. [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Komposition/N-Comp/N-Komp.html?MenuId=WordFormation1150)) und müsste korrekt

> Feinzucker

heißen. Dass das Wort auf der Verpackung in zwei Wörter aufgeteilt wurde, hat wohl gestalterische Gründe.

*Feinzucker* bedeutet das gleiche wie *feiner Zucker*.

Comment: Deppenleerzeichen auf Lebensmittelverpackungen und in der Gastronomie sind sehr üblich. Naja, leider nicht nur dort: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,333774,00.html

Comment: Welch gestalterischer Grund käme in Betracht? Kein Platz für einen Trennstrich ja wohl nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Es ist anzunehmen, dass die Gestalter der Verpackung genug Deutschkenntnisse besitzen, um zu wissen, dass es korrekt `Feinzucker` und nicht `Fein Zucker` heißen muss. Dieses vorausgesetzt, ist die einzige mir logisch erscheinende Erklärung für die abweichende Schreibweise, dass dem Erscheinungsbild mehr Bedeutung beigemessen wurde als der korrekten Schreibweise. Warum die Gestaltung so gewählt wurde, musst du einen Verpackungsdesigner fragen. Das unterliegt ja auch einer gewissen Mode.

Comment: Um zwei Erklärungen miteinander auf größere Plausibilität zu vergleichen müsste man m.E. beide Seiten beleuchten. Man müsste also angeben, welche gestalterische Regel es gebieten sollte, eine falsche Schreibung zu wählen. Wozu dient denn Gestaltung, wenn nicht, den Inhalt zu transportieren? Die Zahl solcher Misbildungen ist ja Legion, und oft findet man "Kartoffel Klöße" u. dgl., wo also "Kartoffel, Klöße" ebenso gemeint sein könnte. Dass die Deutschkenntnisse bestehen bezweifle ich.

Comment: Die These "Verpackungsdesigner können schlecht Deutsch" kann man meiner Meinung nach ausschließen. Bei der Gestaltung eines Produktes geht es vorrangig darum, potentielle Kunden zu dessen Kauf zu bewegen. Mögliche Gründe für das Weglassen des Bindestrichs sind ein moderneres Aussehen in Anlehnung an das Englische, von wo diese Unart vermutlich übernommen wurde oder die Hervorhebung bestimmter Wörter. Es wird wohl vermutet, dass der vorbeilaufende Kunde bei `Premium Qualität` die Schlagwörter schneller aufnimmt als bei der `Premiumqualität`.

Comment: @Deve: Ich finde das sehr dünn. Du vermutest, dass andere vermuten. Kann man Premium Qualität tatsächlich schneller lesen, obwohl es falsch ist? Das wäre zu prüfen. Und was soll an englischem Feinzucker moderner sein? Wer assoziiert mit Fein Zucker (im gleichen Hause auch: Puder Zucker) Modernität? Selbst zu backen ist doch eher retro! (P.S.: Ohne das @ wird der Vorkommentator nicht benachrichtigt, nur der Antworter oder Frager).

Comment: @userunknown: Meinem Empfinden nach würde "Fein- zucker" in zwei Zeilen erstens zerrupft aussehen und den Fokus vom Produkt Zucker wegnehmen. Gestalterisch sehe ich nur zwei Alternativen: "Feinzucker" in einem Wort oder die tatsächliche Variante. In erstem Fall begrenzt das die Schriftgröße, was schon wieder den "Zucker" aus dem Fokus rücken könnte. Ohne repräsentative Studien bleibt das natürlich alles Spekulation...

Comment: @userunknown: "Wozu dient denn Gestaltung, wenn nicht, den Inhalt zu transportieren?" Die Gestaltung dient vornehmlich dazu, den Käufer zum Kauf zu animieren. Alle anderen Fragen sind dagegen zweit- oder drittrangig, inklusive Fragen der korrekten Sprache. Wenn eine Marktforschung ergibt, dass die Bezeichnung "Zucker wo voll krass fein is" den Verkauf steigert, dann kommt eben das auf die Packung, egal, was der Duden sagt (es sei denn, es verstößt gegen irgendwelche gesetzlichen Vorschriften; die Bezeichnung von Lebensmitteln ist ja auch gesetzlich geregelt).

Comment: @Deve  "Verpackungsdesigner können schlecht Deutsch" würde ich nicht so pauschal auschließen. In der Tat stellt man bei Leuten, die im Graphik-Design tätig sind, insgesamt eine schwächer ausgeprägte Orthographieaffinität fest als bei Leuten, die professionell Texte verfassen. (Nun frag mich aber bitte nicht nach einer Liste mit Forschungsliteratur dazu...)

Answer (score 21):

Die abgebildete Kombination "Fein Zucker" ist natürlich grammatikalisch nicht richtig. Um die Eigenschaften einer Sache näher zu beschreiben, bildet man hier ein zusammengesetztes Wort:

> Feinzucker
>
> Puderzucker

Manchmal wird bei Produkten deren Eigenschaft auch als Adverb mit Komma getrennt angefügt:

> Zucker, fein
>
> Salz, grob
>
> Pfeffer, gemahlen

Für die abgebildete Verpackung haben vermutlich die Designer und Werbefachleute das Sagen gehabt und eine grammatikalisch nicht richtige Variante in Kauf genommen.

Comment: Reminds me of "Falle, Schnapp, für Kleintier, grau." :D

Comment: Insbesondere geht mir "Joghurt mild" auf den Senkel, denn das steht buchstäblich auf *allen* Joghurtverpackungen. Es ist eine Manie. (Und noch dazu eine kulinarische Verwirrung. Richtig guter Joghurt muss scharf und sauer sein, nicht mild und lätschig.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Kommt auf die Geschmacksrichtung an: Kirsch-Joghurt darf gerne etwas säuerlicher sein, Vanille-Joghurt bitte nicht so sehr :-P

Answer (score 10):

I don't know, but there is also

[image: feiner zucker]

and

[image]

Comment: Achso! Ich wusste nicht, dass es besseren Zucker gab.

Comment: I believe those attributes are based on regulations and depend on the size of the sugar crystals, not on quality. Feiner Zucker is more coarse than Feinster Zucker.

Comment: Wir warten auf "Puder Zucker", "Gelier Zucker", "Kandis Zucker" und "Trauben Zucker", bevor es zu "Kicher Erbsen", "Wein Berg Schnecken" und "Wal Nuss Eis Creme" geht.

Comment: As a student of German and not a native speaker, the posted example raises the question in my mind: if "feiner zucker" is fine sugar, and "feinster zucker" is finest sugar, then how do you say "finer sugar"?

Comment: @MartyGreen It's a bit hard to find a use for this phrase, but for example *I use finer sugar than usual* could be translated to *Ich verwende feineren Zucker als gewöhnlich*

Comment: @MartyGreen The more interesting question is: how can Puderzucker be even "feiner" than "feinster Zucker" ("Feinstzucker", btw)?

Comment: @dualed: Of course, the most obvious example in this thread would be *Feinster Zucker ist feinerer Zucker als feiner Zucker.*

Comment: @user: Südzucker seems to have products named "Gelier Zucker", "Puder Zucker Mühle", "Würfel Zucker", "Feinster Back Zucker", etc. So it looks as if they do it on purpose. <g>

Comment: @userunknown: Ich musste mehrfach lesen um zu erkennen, dass da nicht “Geiler Zucker” sondern “Gelier Zucker” steht … :-)

Comment: @celtschk   Geiler Fehler!

Answer (score 5):

Das Problem mit dieser Frage ist, dass zur vollständigen Beantwortung mehr nötig ist als nur die Betrachtung der deutschen Sprache.

Korrekt ist, wie in den anderen Antworten bereits dargelegt wurde, dass die Schreibweise "Fein Zucker" grammatikalisch schlicht und einfach falsch ist. Grammatikalisch richtig wäre "Feinzucker", "feiner Zucker" oder "Feiner Zucker" (Der "Satz" beginnt mit "fein", also muss es großgeschrieben werden). Sprachlich gesehen bezeichnet "fein" also eine Eigenschaft des Zuckers; entsprechend gibt es den Würfelzucker, der in Würfelform vorliegt, den Kristallzucker, der aus größeren Kristallen besteht, den Puderzucker, der extrem fein ist, Gelierzucker, der zum Einkochen von Marmelade verwendet wird, usw.

Ursache für diesen grammatikalisch fehlerhaften Aufdruck "Fein Zucker" (wann dieser Name/Aufdruck das erste Mal verwendet worden ist, wäre hier noch sehr informativ) ist das Problem der Reklametreibenden, mehr Aufmerksamkeit für ein Produkt zu generieren (dies fehlt bei den anderen Antworten). Wird nun lediglich eine weitere Packung Zucker ins Regal gestellt, fällt sie nicht weiter auf. Schreibt man "feiner Zucker" darauf, fällt sie nur den Kunden auf, die sowieso feinen Zucker kaufen wollen. Schreibt man jedoch "Fein Zucker" auf die Packung, so fällt diese vielen besonders auf, wenn sonst alle Hersteller keinen grammatikalischen Fehler oder Rechtschreibfehler haben. Diese falsche Schreibweise fällt sogar im Vorbeigehen auf, da sie etwas "Besonderes" ist, und somit wurde das Ziel (kurzfristig) erreicht, mehr Aufmerksamkeit zu generieren. Flaut diese Aufmerksamkeit ab, muss man sich das Nächste ausdenken. Leider hat diese Praxis eine unglückliche Auswirkung auf die deutsche Sprache.

Damit lässt sich die gestellte Frage so beantworten: *Um eine möglichst hohe Aufmerksamkeit für das Produkt zu erreichen, wurde der Produktname absichtlich grammatikalisch falsch geschrieben.*

Comment: Du meinst _orthographisch_, wo du _grammatikalisch_ schreibst, denn letzteres meint üblicherweise zumindest auch Satzgrammatik und nicht Wortgrammatik.

Comment: Aber jetzt, wo es alle falsch schreiben, wäre eine Variante mit Bindestrich (also richtig) auffälliger.

Comment: @cgnieder: wenn man die anderen Produktnamen von Südzucker sieht, kann man das wohl vermuten: "Gelier Zucker", "Puder Zucker Mühle", "Würfel Zucker", "Feinster Back Zucker", usw.

Comment: Überhaupt sollte die Vergewaltigung der deutschen Sprache auf Produktverpackungen mit Strafe belegt werden. Außerdem auch das Aufstellen absurder Behauptungen in der Werbung.

Answer (score 2):

In Österreich drückt der Name klar aus, ob da Kristalle sind oder nicht.

Es handelt sich dann also um *Feinkristallzucker*.

http://www.wiener-zucker.at/content/de/produkte/produkte/1/feinkristallzucker.php

Comment: Auch beliebt: Kristallzucker, Würfel Zucker.

Comment: *Puderzucker* hingegen ist in Oesterreich keine gute Wahl: siehe [pudern](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/pudern) :)

Comment: @Sebastian: Dann eben "Staub Zucker".